# Honeypot in custom webforms (manual)

Tags: 7, webforms, advertising

I'm making a custom form (fields are added by using `drupal_render`), but since I have Honeypot enabled for all my web forms, when I submit a form, I get the following message:

> There was a problem with your form submission. Please wait X seconds and try again.

That's because Honeypot markup isn't being included in my custom form.

I have two options:

1. Disable Honeypot for this form (not possible through module settings from Drupal administration menu). **How can I add an exception?**
2. Enable Honeypot manually (with `drupal_render`s I guess).

Honeypot docs is so poor, so I also have tried to add Honeypot markup manually in this way:

  `<?php print drupal_render($form['honeypot_time']); ?>
  <?php print drupal_render($form['url']); ?>`

It adds the markup actually, but it isn't fixing yet.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [module documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/honeypot/using-honeypot), you can do this:

> If you want to add honeypot to your own forms, or to any form through
>   your own module's hook_form_alter's, you can simply place the
>   following function call inside your form builder function (or inside a
>   hook_form_alter):

```
<?php
  honeypot_add_form_protection($form, $form_state, array('honeypot', 'time_restriction'));
?>
```

> Note that you can enable or disable either the honeypot field, or the
>   time restriction on the form by including or not including the option
>   in the array.
>
> You can also use [Honeypot's API](http://drupalcode.org/project/honeypot.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/honeypot.api.php) to modify the time delay for forms,
>   add or remove protections for certain forms, etc.